# xlrd python library

Tags: python, xlrd

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("file.xls")

wb.sheet_names()

sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for item in sh.col(0):
    value = unicode(item.value)
    if value.startswith("cheap"):
        print value
```

when i trying this code, interpritator return me:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open_workbook'
whats wrong? in all manuals typeed this code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you've accidentally created your own xlrd.py file that is being found before the real one.

The solution is to find the imposter and delete it.  Try `import xlrd; print xlrd.__file__` to find the culprit :-)

P.S.  You will need to delete both the .py file and its .pyc cached version.

Comment: +1. However I'd suggest *rename* the .py file and delete any .pyc file ... a common scenario is that one is trying out a new module `foo` and writes a little script file named `foo.py`.